# How to insert records into a Self referencing table via Fluent nHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql-server, recursion, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have created a self-referencing Categories Table [MsSQL 2012] with Fluent nhibernate, during testing, I’ve just been adding the data manually via SSMS; 'but now I wish to do it through code, I’m a little lost?'

```
public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<CategoryPartRecord> {
    public CategoryMap() {
        Table("Ceck_CategoryPartRecord");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();

        Map(x => x.Name);

        //Relationships-
        // Recursive:
        // [Category]---<[Category]
        References(x => x.ParentCategory)
        HasMany(x => x.Categories)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

I have tried two approaches:

```
using (var transactionB = session.BeginTransaction())
{
CategoryPartRecord Cat1 = new CategoryPartRecord() { Name = "Exterior" };
CategoryPartRecord Cat2 = new CategoryPartRecord() { Name = "Interior" };
CategoryPartRecord Cat3 = new CategoryPartRecord() { Name = "Garden" };

CategoryPartRecord Cat4 = new CategoryPartRecord() { Name = "Paint" };

Cat1.Categories.Add(Cat4);

session.Save(Cat1);
session.Save(Cat2);
session.Save(Cat3);
transactionB.Commit();
}
```

.

```
using (var transactionBB = session.BeginTransaction()) 
{
var Cat = session.Load<CategoryPartRecord>(1); //Contains "Exterior"
CategoryPartRecord Cat2 = new CategoryPartRecord() { Name = "Paint" };

Cat.Categories.Add(Cat2);

session.Save(Cat);
transactionBB.Commit();
}
```

Both add the new record containing "Paint", but dont link the relationship correctly, as "CategoryPartRecord_id" is always NULL -- Am I missing something really obvious because neither work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, hazarding a guess - inversion on a recursion would be more than interesting, so to eliminate any funny behaviour, change your mapping to this and let me know how you get on?

```
        References(x => x.ParentCategory).Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        HasMany(x => x.Categories)
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```